# Problem with wireless router, always stay local

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

Hey, for some reason my wireless router only allows me access to my local network. I've tried to reset the router and I've followed the set-up wizard and I've also done the advanced set-up and nothing is working.

### Wireless Router

108MBps Wireless Firewall Router WGT624 v2

================

### Modem

Motorola - SB5101 Surfboard issued by Atlantic Boardband

Comment: Does the router say it's connecting to the internet?

Comment: Well it says that it's connected but on my computer it says connected local only, I'm using Windows 7 and everything is good...unsure why this is happening:S

Answer (score 1):

pretty interesting if this solution works - according to the documentation you need a cross over cable going from modem to switch/hub. That seems odd and old school for certain. Does the router get a non-local IP on the WAN side? Can you get internet connection when the cable modem is directly connected to 1 PC?

Answer (score 0):

My first look would be to hardware. Make sure that the modem has the signal and make sure the signal is getting to the router.

Comment: Everything is there, no problems with hardware on both ends...and im unsure...:S

Answer (score 0):

First, log into your router and try to ping from the router to your primary DNS. If that is successful, then your router is not having connectivity issues. The next step is to verify that your connection between your router and your computer works. First plug your computer into your network and try a wired connection. Are you getting a proper IP address? Can you ping the router? Can you ping the primary DNS from your computer? Can you resolve a url? If so then you know your router is routing properly and DNS is set up properly. The next step is to test the wireless. When you connect, do you get a proper IP address? Can you ping the router? can you ping the primary DNS?
If you run into any problem with any of these steps, then you know what part of the router configuration to zero in on.